# C# Datetime short year with national conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, format

How can I make DateTime.ToString() put out strings in such a way, that it looks like this in Germany: dd.MM.yy and like this in the USA MM/dd/yy and everywhere else for that matter, with year always having two characters, but the format of the date, being specific to culture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to use `DateTime.ToString` since it's using the current culture if you don't specify a different:

```
string result = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

The `/` will be replaced with the correct date separators of the current culture.

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

**Edit**: "what about `dd MM` and `MM dd` part?"

Good question, this is my try:

```
string shortDate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string result = dt.ToString(shortDate.Replace("yyyy", "yy"));
```

Comment: what about `dd MM` and `MM dd` part?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
textBox1.Text =  DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

or:

```
 textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

For more formatting details please see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN